# Android Studio singningConfigs, is it safe to include the password?

Tags: java, android

My question is that there is a section in the gradle file called signingConfigs.
Is it a problem if the password is entered here?
Should I be worried about this?
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should **NOT** do this. These params are there for testing convenience.

We should **NEVER** store **ANY** crucial, personal, sensitive information as plaintext.

The testing key passwords and stuff just use dummy values. The actual release key we generate via AndroidStudio or Java keystore directly.

For PlayStore app releases, key files I usually let Google assign, manage and maintain via Developer Dashboard.